# Formatting correctly the p2pBootstrapPeers in OCR .toml in Chainlink

Tags: chainlink, toml

When setting the .toml for the OCR job in the Chainlink:

The documentation says:
https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/types/offchain-reporting/

`p2pBootstrapPeers = [ "/dns4/chain.link/tcp/1234/$PEERID", ]`

does this imply that when writing this in the .toml job file that every single node which is part of the OCR has to be added to p2pBootstrapPeers like this for example?

`p2pBootstrapPeers = ["/dns4/chain.link/tcp/1234/p2p/$PEERID-1",`
`"/dns4/chain.link/tcp/1234/p2p/$PEERID-2",`
`"/dns4/chain.link/tcp/1234/p2p/$PEERID-3",`
`"/dns4/chain.link/tcp/1234/p2p/$PEERID-4"]`

Is the p2pBootstrapPeers actually a list of all other peers?

Answer (score 0):

As they said in the official documentation, `p2pBootstrapPeers` is the list of `libp2p` dial addresses of the other bootstrap nodes helping oracle nodes find one another on the network.

Not necessarily all peers in the network are bootstrap nodes. A bootstrapping node is a node that provides initial configuration information to newly joining oracle nodes so that they may successfully join the network.

The difference between Bootstrap Node and Oracle Node is that Bootstrap Node must have `isBootstrapPeer` property set to `true`. Every OCR cluster requires at least one bootstrap node.

`p2pBootstrapPeers` is an array, so your syntax is correct.

Comment: Does this imply that if I had a bootstrap node and 4 oracle nodes my p2pBootstrapPeers = [PeerID1, PeerID2, PeerID3, PeerID4] would be correct?

Comment: No, only bootstrap nodes should be in the p2pBootstrapPeers array.

Comment: Lets assume I only have one one boostrap node and 4 oracle nodes, then the p2pBootstrapPeers = [] of the bootstrap node is empty. Then the p2pBootstrapPeers of every oracle nodes has the reference to the one and only bootstrap node like this: p2pBootstrapPeers = [ "/dns4/chain.link/tcp/1234/$PEERID-of-the-bootstrap-node", ] is that correct?

Comment: Question: in the link "/dns4/chain.link/tcp/1234/$PEERID".... chain.link is actually the IP address of my node. Is that correct?